# proof that the extended real number is equal to outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the extended real number is defined as
$$ N(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k) : A \subseteq  \bigcup_{K=1}^{\infty} I_k\right\}$$
where the $I_k$ are open intervals of the form $(a_k,b_k)$. Show that for each set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it holds that
$N(A) = m^*(A)$.

I'm a bit confused, as the definitions are the same. According to me, I should propose a covering and see that the infimum is the same, but since the definitions are identical, it trivially holds.

Comment: in my mind this is just equal by definition. Did you perhaps define the Lebesgue outer measure as the infimum over a different collection of sets? Perhaps closed intervals, or mixed intervals or something else?

Comment: With cut-and-pasted-out-of-context snippets like this one it's usually hard to be definitive. Here's my wild guess: the terminology *extended real number* makes me think that perhaps the intention is simply to alert the reader that $N(A)$ takes values in *set of extended real numbers* $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, as opposed to taking values in the real numbers $\mathbb R$ themselves.

Comment: @peek-a-boo the definition that I have for Lebesgue outer measure is the same 

$$ m^{*}(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ell(I_k) : A \subseteq  \bigcup_{K=1}^{\infty} I_k\right\}$$

Comment: Yea… I would just ignore and move on. If this is an assignment question, then ask your professor to clarify.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I think I've found the difference. N(A) is defined only in open intervals, while m*(A) is defined for every interval.